# Returning a Boolean from a method

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

My program is supposed to check if an integer is in a random integer. It will return true or false. For example: 45903 contains 4: true. For some reason; my code kept running after i entered the digit. Some thing is wrong with my containDigit() method but i can't seem to figure out. i'm very new to boolean.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*; 

public class checkNum {


 public static void main(String[] args) { 

  // Create a new Scanner object 
   Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  // Create a new Random objects 
 Random rand = new Random();

   // Declare a integer value that is getting the value in the range of[10000, 99999] 
   int randomNum = rand.nextInt(90000)+10000;

  // Show the random value to user by using of System.out.println 
 System.out.println(randomNum);

  // Type a prompt message as "Enter a digit" 
 System.out.println("Enter a digit: ");

  // Assign user input to integer value 
  int digit = console.nextInt();

  // Define a boolean value that is assigned by calling the method "containDigit(12345,5)" 

  // Show the output 
  System.out.println(randomNum+ " contains" +
                     digit+" " + containDigit(randomNum,digit));

 } 

 public static boolean containDigit(int first, int second) { 
   int digi = 10000;

  // Define all statements to check digits of "first" 
   while (first > 0) {
    digi = first % 10;
    digi = first / 10;
}

   if (digi == second){
     return true;
   }else {
   return false;
   }
  // If it has "second" value in these digits, return true, 
  // If not, return false 

  // return a boolean value such as "return false"; 
  return false;
 } 

}
```

Comment: Time to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: Its running forever because of infinite loop. `while (first > 0)`. `first` is always greater than 0. Its the value of `digi` that changes and the value of `first` remains same, ie, `>0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand why are you assigning `first %10`to `digi` and then immediately overwriting `digi` with `first / 10`.

Your while loop may never exit as `first` might always be greater than 0. It might never be entered as `first` might be equal to 0. You might want to do this:

```
  while (first/10 == 0) {
    first = first % 10;
     if (first == second)
        return true;
  }
  if(first%10 == second)
     return true;

return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not restricted with way of solution, I can suggest below:

```
return (randomInt + "").contains(digit + "");
```

Comment: You mean `return (String.valueOf(randomInt)).contains(String.valueOf(digit))`, right?

Comment: Yes what you wrote is the proper way. Also you can use Integer.toString(i) as well. When you concat int with string, compiler converts int to string then do concat, result is a new string.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop never exits:

```
while (first > 0) {
    digi = first % 10;
    first = first / 10; // i believe this should be first instead of digit        
}
```

You should add a simple `print` statement to check what your `digit` and `first` variables' values are:

```
System.out.println("digi: "+digi);
System.out.println("first: "+first);
```